# SQL connect AS and PLUS

Tags: sql, select

I have problem with something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), iv.[IssueDate], 11) AS [YY/MM/DD] + ','
FROM dbo.[InvoiceView] iv
WHERE iv.[Id]=5;
```

When I delete `+ ','` everything works fine and date format is properly so the problem is with this `+` sign.  Could you help me how can I fix it?

Comment: you mean this: `+ ',' AS [YY/MM/DD]`?

Comment: For what purpose you think you are using `+ ','`?

Comment: It's more complicated, is't formatter to save data in file and i need few informations after commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the comma before you define an alias using `AS` like so:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), iv.[IssueDate], 11) + ',' AS [YY/MM/DD]
```

The alias will apply to the whole column, not a part of it the way you define it.

Comment: One more question, what if I would add something after comma? Let's say `+ ',' +` ? Where should the 2nd `+` goes?

Comment: Everything from that column must be before AS